# why do nested parentheses cause empty strings in this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, parentheses

Why do nested parentheses cause empty strings in this regex?

```
var str = "ab((cd))ef";
var arr = str.split(/([\)\(])/);
console.log(arr); // ["ab", "(", "", "(", "cd", ")", "", ")", "ef"]
```

what I want to achieve is this

```
["ab", "(", "(", "cd", ")", ")", "ef"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The outer parameters in your regular expression act as capturing group. From the documentation of split (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing
>   parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results
>   (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are
>   spliced into the output array.

You didn't say exactly what you want to achieve with your regex, perhaps you want something like this:

```
var str = "ab((cd))ef";
var arr = str.split(/[\)\(]+/);
console.log(arr); // ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
```

**EDIT:**

Each parenthesis matches the regex individually, so the array looks like this (one line per parenthesis matched:

```
['ab', '('] // matched (
['ab', '(', '', '('] // matched ( (between the last two matches is the empty string
['ab', '(', '', '(', 'cd', ')'] // matched )
['ab', '(', '', '(', 'cd', ')', '', ')'] // matched )
['ab', '(', '', '(', 'cd', ')', '', ')', 'ef'] // string end
```

**EDIT2:**

Required output is: `["ab", "(", "(", "cd", ")", ")", "ef"]`

I am not sure you can do that with one split. The fastest and safest way to do it is to just filter out the empty strings. I doubt a solution with a single split for a regexp exists.

```
var str = "ab((cd))ef";
var arr = str.split(/([\)\(])/).filter(function(item) { return item !== '';});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I want the parentheses captured, but I do not want the empty strings (I've added the required output to the question)

Comment: So, the effect it is not limited to parentheses

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question!

I'm unsure as to why, but if you chain

```
.filter(function(el){ return el !== "";});
```

onto your split, you can get rid of the empty strings:

```
var str = "ab((cd))ef";
var arr = str.split(/([\)\(])/).filter(function(el) { return el !== "";});
console.log(arr); // ["ab", "(", "(", "cd", ")", ")", "ef"]
```